# Auto Voltage Selection between 12V and 5V for Irrigation Controller

Tags: arduino, voltage, mosfet, motor, circuit-design

**Background**

I am working on a hobby project, it will be a general purpose open source irrigation controller.

I haven't built the PCB yet but I want to power the board either through the USB port for small valves and through 12V to 24V for larger ones. Here is a block diagram of what I have in mind.

[image]

I am sharing the whole power section of the PCB so that the reader gets a better idea of the system.
[image]

To select between these voltages I thought of using a circuit I usually use to select between VBUS and a single cell Lion/Lipo battery. The spice simulation gives an acceptable result as seen below. The green line is the voltage at Source of the PMOS and the blue line at the Drain.

[image]

**Question**

However I am unsure if this is the "good" way of doing it, since VCC will also power the valves . Which are inductive loads. I will be using the circuit below to drive the Valves albeit with different components. I don't have any previous experience designing motor drivers.

[image]

I would very much appreciate it if you could point out any errors I may have in my line of thinking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatic switching between external 5V and USB bus power supplies](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274338/automatic-switching-between-external-5v-and-usb-bus-power-supplies)

Comment: @MarcusMüller is there an advantage to using his voltage selector compared to mine? His have more mosfets.

Comment: Have you considered using a simple mechanical relay for swapping between the 5V USB and the higher voltage? Just a 2 throw relay energized with the higher voltage.  
The mosfet circuit may be an elegant way to do the switching, however if the switching mosfet were to short out (say from a spike on the line), your USB and what ever is behind that might quickly become toast.